# Laravel - Removing jobs on queue based on model association

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

I'm new to jobs and queues.

At the moment, I'm only really using the ->later() method on a Mail. This places each mail on the default queue.

There are instances where I need cancel jobs on the queue related to a specific model ID. I don't really see any reference to deleting pending jobs in the queue - only deleting  / clearing failed.

In Telescope, there are tags showing the Model IDs associated with each pending job.

There are a few things I was hoping to do:

- Delete all jobs associated with a specific model ID
- Listen for the execution of a job based on a specific model ID, so I may update the database table with the date/timestamp of when the job actually executed. (users can queue emails to send hours in advance and I'd like to log when their customer actually receives the email)
- Remove record associated with job since it should not exist if the email didn't actually get sent.

Hoping for some advice on how to solve this problem of needing to manage jobs in this fashion.

I'm using Redis if that makes any difference.